# Migration from TestNG to JUnit4 - dealing with static methods required by junitparams @Parameters annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng, junit4

I have a problem with migration of some tests from TestNG to JUnit.

This is how the tests were looking before I have tried to migrate them:

```
@Autowired
private ContentRepository contentRepository;

@DataProvider(name = "getAllPossibleContents")
private Object[][] getAllContents() {
    List<Object[]> allContents = new ArrayList<>();
    contentRepository.findAll().forEach(content -> allContents.add(new Object[] {content.getId()}));
    Object[][] result = new Object[allContents.size()][];
    return result;
}

@Test(dataProvider = "getAllPossibleContents")
public void testAddingContext(Long contentId) {
    Content content = contentRepository.findOne(contentId);
    assertEquals(10, content.getContext().size());
    assertTrue(content.getContext().contains(somethingNotImportant));
}
```

I have changed the code to:

```
@Autowired
private ContentRepository contentRepository;

public static Object[][] getAllContents() {
    List<Object[]> allContents = new ArrayList<>();
    contentRepository.findAll().forEach(content -> allContents.add(new Object[] {content.getId()}));
    Object[][] result = new Object[allContents.size()][];
    return result;
}

@Test
@Parameters(method = "getAllContents")
public void testAddingContext(Long contentId) {
    Content content = contentRepository.findOne(contentId);
    assertEquals(10, content.getContext().size());
    assertTrue(content.getContext().contains(somethingNotImportant));
}
```

The problem is that I get an error from my IDE:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field contentRepository
```

And this is an obvious one for me, the method providing data must be static.

Is there any possibility to change this code so I can use the `contentRepository` with parametrized tests? I have read a bit about using the classical JUnit approach (`@RunWith(Parametrized.class)`), but it seems that the data providing methods in this approach should be static too...

Comment: testng wraps junit and extends functionality.. why ?

Comment: @Infern0 don't ask me, not my code...